# How to use a github package instead of the built-in version?

Tags: package, spacemacs

I tried to install `verilog-mode` from github to replace the version built in to Emacs.

I'm using `spacemacs`.  I created a layer for `verilog` and added `verilog-mode` in `packages.el`:

```
(verilog-mode :location (recipe
                         :fetcher github
                         :repo "veripool/verilog-mode"))
```

I have enabled the `verilog` layer but the `verilog-mode` is still the built-in version.

**How could I make spacemacs use the version from Github?**

Answer (score 2):

To install a package by using a layer, you need to add the pacakge to the layer's packages list, write an init function for the package, and enable the layer. It appears that you did not write an init function. The init function is necessary for Spacemacs to install the package, but it can be empty if no configuration is needed for the package.

When trying to override a built-in package with a newer version, use the `:min-version` keyword to specify a version that is higher than the built-in one and lower or equal to the desired version. `:min-version` should be a version string, similar in format to `emacs-version`.

Assuming your layer is called verilog, its `packages.el` file should look like this:

```lisp
(defconst verilog-packages
  '((verilog-mode :location (recipe :fetcher github
                                    :repo "veripool/verilog-mode"
                                    :min-version "1"))))

(defun verilog/init-verilog-mode ()
  ;; ... verilog configuration goes here ...
  )
```

And of course don't forget to enable the layer by adding it to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`.

To make sure that `:min-version` is newer than the built-in version, you can use this next small snippet. It is meant to be used interactively before installing the newer version:

```lisp
(package-installed-p 'verilog-mode (version-to-list "1"))
```

Another approach is to install verilog-mode as an additional package. In this approach, you install the package by adding it to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`. The same entries that fit in a layer's packages list also fit in `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`. In your case, you'd add this as an entry:

```lisp
(verilog-mode :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "veripool/verilog-mode" :min-version "1"))
```

And any configuration for verilog-mode goes in `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

Comment: I do have a init function `init-verilog-mode`, but it still doesn't install from github.

Comment: Did you name the function `init-verilog-mode`? The function name must be `<layer>/init-<package>`, so in this case `verilog/init-verilog-mode` (I fixed the name in the answer)

Comment: I did name the function verilog/init-verilog-mode and I can see the variables I set in that function have the expected value. Just the verilog-mode is still the builtin one.

Comment: Earlier I didn't run the code myself. Now I have and realized that `:min-version` needs to be specified as well. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think the verilog-mode is a little bit tricky. I don't know how to find the version number. Now I have to manually copy the repo to `local` directory under `verilog` layer and install it from there.

Comment: You can guess a number that's newer than the built-in's version, the answer shows how to check if the guess is good. Using "1" works for me. The version of packages installed through a fetcher will usually be a timestamp of the package's last commit date (the same as MELPA packages), so it's considered newer than "1" (in this case in this case it's "20160724.2332")